# On a research perspective, do physical layer rules come under the term "wireless protocol"

Tags: wireless

My opinion is that the physical layer techniques and routing techniques both come under the term "wireless protocol". In some special cases, I have even seen physical layer protocols that are highly dependant on routing success and vice versa.

Hence, I would like to know if it's right of me to mention the term "wireless sensor network protocols" and expect it to incorporate physical layer technology as well.

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking, but there does seem to be a fundamental error here: protocols are about *what* you say and how you encapsulate and confirm it, not about the *mechanics* of signalling itself, although they may do well to be informed by the possible failures thereof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may not understand what you mean by "come under" but let's see if I can properly make the case for the answer at the bottom.

Physical layer and protocols are two different things.

Simple example is what ham radio operators call CW.  Continuous Wave.  It means to send a signal from a radio transmitter to a receiver.  It is called a carrier wave.  It would sound like a long continuous beep.  The only information you can glean from it is that there is a transmitter that you can hear.  That is the physical layer.

But then when you use a hand key to interrupt that transmitter's signal in a way that others can understand, then you have imposed a protocol (Morse Code) on top of the physical medium of radio via carrier wave.  AM and FM stations do the same.  They take a carrier wave and change (modulate) it in ways that can be understood after demodulation.  The medium is radio, but the physical layer is really the carrier wave.

Similar for fiber optics.  It all starts with a light beam going down a fiber.  In fact, it may be multiple beams of different colors.  Those are the carrier waves which provide the physical layer.

The physical layer is the method of signaling.  Radio, cables of various kinds, fiber optics, etc.

[Here is a good article that explains what physical layer means](http://www.studytonight.com/computer-networks/osi-model-physical-layer)

Protocols are the ways those signaling methods are used.  Like framing and addressing of packets for routing, then the information inside the packets, and onward up through the OSI stack.

There are many wireless protocols like WiFi and Bluetooth, PACTOR, TAPR-2, Morse, but they simply provide the carrier.

Then data is imposed on the carrier by other layers of the OSI stack which provide the routing information, causing information to be communicated.

[Here is an article that describes the OSI layers and what they mean](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/24961/osi-protocols)

So no, I would not use that exact phrase in a research paper as you describe.

*But you are very close.  You should be able to come up with a very succinct phrase that means what you intend and conforms to the OSI model.*

Comment: Of course, if you are writing this for high school nobody would notice the difference.  College, maybe, depending on the professor.  Masters, definitely clarify it, and PhD, give references.   -  Remember what they say:  BS = Bull****, MS = More ****, PhD = Pile it higher and deeper.  ;-)

Comment: Carriers, and MorseCode modulated carriers, need a Beat Frequency Oscillator, if I correctly recall the front panel of my Hallicrafters S-38 6-tube radio.

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  The BFO is used so you can zero-beat the signal so your transmitter goes back on the same frequency.  Once you are exactly on frequency you can't hear it unless you use the local BFO as a receiver offset so you get an audible tone in the receiver without changing the transmitter frequency.  I used to have a Hallicrafters SX-68 receiver.  I loved that old boat anchor.   Those were the days, my friend.